# How to get the link from archetype single url picker in umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I create the archetype field with multiple data like Title image content link. I can get the value for title content value but link show the output.

[ { "name": "View Website", "url": "www.google.com", "target": "_blank", "icon": "icon-link" } ]

**How to get the Url from link**

@{

```
var property = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<ArchetypeModel>("exhibitorLogos");
```

}

@if (property != null && property.Any())
{

```
foreach (var item in property)
{


    var imageId = item.GetValue<int>("image");
    var imgurlbannerLogoUrl = Umbraco.Media(imageId.ToString()).Url;
    var text = item.GetValue<string>("name");
    var content = item.GetValue<string>("content");
    var link = item.GetValue<string>("link");


    <h1>@text</h1>
    <img src="@imgurlbannerLogoUrl"/>
    <p>@content</p>
    <a href="@link">ReadMore</a>

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little on your version of Umbraco and the version of URL Picker you're using, try the below.

Add a using statement:

```
@using RJP.MultiUrlPicker.Models
```

Then do one of the below.

Either this:

```
foreach (var item in property)
{


    var imageId = item.GetValue<int>("image");
    var imgurlbannerLogoUrl = Umbraco.Media(imageId.ToString()).Url;
    var text = item.GetValue<string>("name");
    var content = item.GetValue<string>("content");
    var link = item.GetValue<Link>("link");


    <h1>@text</h1>
    <img src="@imgurlbannerLogoUrl"/>
    <p>@content</p>
    <a href="@link">ReadMore</a>

}
```

Or this:

```
foreach (var item in property)
{
    var imageId = item.GetValue<int>("image");
    var imgurlbannerLogoUrl = Umbraco.Media(imageId.ToString()).Url;
    var text = item.GetValue<string>("name");
    var content = item.GetValue<string>("content");
    var link = item.GetValue<IEnumerable<Link>>("link").FirstOrDefault();


    <h1>@text</h1>
    <img src="@imgurlbannerLogoUrl"/>
    <p>@content</p>
    <a href="@link">ReadMore</a>

}
```

Then you can simply do something like the following:

```
<a href="@link.Url" target="@link.Target">@link.Name</a>
```

Comment: For link it show The Type or Namespace name"link" Could not be found (AreaReference you missing a directive or assembly reference)

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad - you'll need to add a @using RJP.MultiUrlPicker.Models - I've added to my answer too :)

Comment: Please mark my answer as the solution to your problem :)

Comment: The type or namespace name 'RJP' could not be found. Can you help me @Mikkel?

Comment: @hubert17 - you will need to install the RJP Nuget package, then the RJP.MultiUrlPicker.Models should be available :)
https://www.nuget.org/packages/RJP.UmbracoMultiUrlPicker/